# Angular8-10, PrimeNG10 `p-menu` throws error

Tags: angular, primeng-menu

I created a new Angular 10 app (have also tried with ng 8 and 9):

`primeng-menu>ng new primeng-menu`

Installed the PrimeNG modules:

`npm install primeng --save` and `npm install primeicons --save`

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "~10.1.1",
  "@angular/common": "~10.1.1",
  "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.1",
  "@angular/core": "~10.1.1",
  "@angular/forms": "~10.1.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.1",
  "@angular/router": "~10.1.1",
  "primeicons": "^4.0.0",
  "primeng": "^10.0.0",
  "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
  "tslib": "^2.0.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
},
```

angular.json:

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
          "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuModule } from 'primeng/menu';
import { MenuItem, MessageService } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  items: MenuItem[];

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [{
      label: 'Options',
      items: [{
        label: 'Update',
        icon: 'pi pi-refresh',
        command: () => {
          this.update();
        }
      },
      {
        label: 'Delete',
        icon: 'pi pi-times',
        command: () => {
          this.delete();
        }
      }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: 'Navigate',
      items: [{
        label: 'Angular Website',
        icon: 'pi pi-external-link',
        url: 'http://angular.io'
      },
      {
        label: 'Router',
        icon: 'pi pi-upload',
        routerLink: '/fileupload'
      }
      ]
    }
    ];
  }

  update() {
    this.messageService.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Success', detail: 'Data Updated' });
  }

  delete() {
    this.messageService.add({ severity: 'warn', summary: 'Delete', detail: 'Data Deleted' });
  }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<h5>Basic</h5>
<p-menu [model]="items"></p-menu>

<h5>Overlay</h5>
<button type="button" pButton icon="pi pi-bars" label="Show" (click)="menu.toggle($event)"> </button>
<p-menu #menu [popup]="true" [model]="items"></p-menu>
```

When I run `ng serve` it will not compile.  I get `error NG8001: 'p-menu' is not a known element:`

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.html:3:1 - error NG8001: 'p-menu' is not a known element:
1. If 'p-menu' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-menu' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

3 <p-menu [model]="items"></p-menu>
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
src/app/app.component.html:3:9 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'model' since it isn't a known property of 'p-menu'.
1. If 'p-menu' is an Angular component and it has 'model' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-menu' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

3 <p-menu [model]="items"></p-menu>
```

I followed all the instructions on PrimeNG's site.  Have I missed something?  Has anyone else gotten `PrimeNG10 Menu` to work with Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrimeNG's `Getting Started` and/or `Menu` documentation fails to mention the following:

In the `app.module.ts`  you need to import:

`import { MenuModule } from 'primeng/menu';`

`import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';`

`import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';`

and add them to the imports.

In the header of index.html add this link `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css" />`.

In the `angular.json` add a theme style `"node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",`

In the `app.component.ts` update the constructor with `, private primengConfig: PrimeNGConfig` from 'primeng/api'.

Add this statement at the top of the `ngOnInit` `this.primengConfig.ripple = true;`

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you forgot is to add Menumodule to your app.module.ts

```
import {MenuModule} from 'primeng/menu';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ Menumodule]
})
export class AppModule { }
```